# Make javascript execute upon clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, calculator

Ive got this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function showTab(name) {
        $('div.fruit').not('#' + name).hide();
        var $div = $('#' + name).show();
        $('span', $div).each(function() {
            $(this).text($(this).data('val') * number);
        });
    }

    $('#dropdown').change(function () {
        showTab($(this).val());
    });

    showTab($('#dropdown').val());
});
```

And I would like it to execute upon clicking Submit button.

Please check fiddle to see how the script exactly works. Any easy way to do it?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/QgfNj/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a submit button for this is a little redundant, as updating the UI after a POST request is pointless as the new request will result in the page being changed. Instead, I used a standard button for this:

```
<input type="button" id="update" value="Update" />
```

```js
$('#update').click(function() { 
    showTab($('#dropdown').val());
});
```

[**Update fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/QgfNj/1/)

If you do want this update to be done after submitting the form you need to do the calculation on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the event.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    showTab(name)
});
```

I updated your fiddle.

Comment: It seems to work however - when i move the submit button to be placed in one line right after the dropdown, following error occurs upon pressing button
{"error": "Please use POST request"}